# Inverters with tied outputs, different inputs

Tags: digital-logic

consider we have two inverters whose outputs are tied together and each inverter has a different propagation delay.

If we apply a periodic square wave to one inverter and a delayed version of the same square wave to the other one, what should the output look like ?

Comment: ... exactly the same as two inverters with the same prop delay fed the same input signal.

Comment: Depends on the inverter's output stage design.

Comment: Tell us what do you think will happen.